# Sudden ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 while seeding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, seeding

While working on my Rails app I was experimenting with some way to crop images, I went from [Rails Casts #182](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images) , back to what I previously had and then to this [blog post](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3951-Cropping-Images-using-jCrop-jQuery-plugin-in-Rails-5), after finishing setting all up, I decided to restart my database and seed it, however I got `ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` when I tried to seed my db.

I've never encountered this error before and after some small research I found this is due to some characters not being able to be read by ruby, however, after skimming my code I've found no difference between what I had before I started with cropping images and after further examining I've yet to find the cause.

It also doesn't help that I've yet to learn how to read and trace rails/rake bugs, here is what I get:

```
rails aborted!
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:118:in `==='
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:118:in `blank?'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:131:in `is_path?'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:97:in `size'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:140:in `empty?'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:120:in `cache!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:44:in `block in cache'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:42:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:42:in `map'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:42:in `cache'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:300:in `main_image='
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:70:in `main_image='
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:46:in `public_send'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:46:in `_assign_attribute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:40:in `block in _assign_attributes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in `_assign_attributes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `_assign_attributes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:33:in `assign_attributes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:319:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:65:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:65:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:50:in `create!'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/seeds.rb:60:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:549:in `load_seed'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:268:in `load_seed'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:196:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:14:in `block in run_rake_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:11:in `run_rake_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My main question is where exactly could this error be happening? so far I've learned through experience that it could be either the `seeds.rb` or the model( in this case `event.rb`) however I don't see anything different and I had them both working before, I was even able to upload images and seed them no problem until I implemented and removed the code from the Rails Cast and implemented the code in the blog post, any direction into the solution will be of great help.

Here is the seed from the model, it was working fine beforehand.

```
Event.create!(
    name: "  1", 
    spanish_description: "El mejor programa para este sábado con los peques ! #kids #gratis #petfriendly. En Kuchitril. De 6 a 10 pm. #localmarket #tendencias #buenavibra. #corranlavoz!",
    english_description: "El mejor programa para este sábado con los peques ! #kids #gratis #petfriendly. En Kuchitril. De 6 a 10 pm. #localmarket #tendencias #buenavibra. #corranlavoz!",
    place_name: "mamita's",
    place_type: "beach club",
    address: "Calle 28 Norte Mza 10, Lote 8, Centro", 
    county: 'meh',
    city: "Playa del Carmen",
    state: "Quintana Roo",
    postal_code: 77710,

    user_id: 1,
    main_image: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'test.jpg')),
    sub_images: [File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'chinchi.jpg'))],


    eventdates_attributes:[{ 
      start_date: Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)"),
      finish_date: Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)"),
      start_hour: "08:00am",
      finish_hour: "11:00am",
    }],

    tickets_attributes:[{ 
      ticket_type: "Solo una vez",
      price: 100,
      currency: "mxn",
      quantity: 150,
      description: "Un boleto muy divertido!"
    }, { 
      ticket_type: "Otra vez",
      price: 150,
      currency: "mxn",
      quantity: 150,
      description: "Un boleto muy divertido!"
    }]
)
```

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** So I decided to just return to previous commits just to not deal with this problem anymore, and for some reason the error keeps popping up, which leads me to believe there is a problem with the platform I'm using, which is Cloud9, I've also read this isn't a problem that should be happening on Rails 5.0

Comment: What version of Ruby do you use? Did you ensure that your editor saves the files in UTF-8? How does you seeds file for that model look like?

Comment: added the seed to the question, I'm using ruby 2.3.0, how do I ensure my editor saves in UTF-8? I always took this for granted until now.

Answer (score 4):

I found the cause of the problem, I was using `mount_uploaders` for a singular upload, making the upload an array and thus creating the error. changing it to `mount_uploader` was the solution, you really have to pay attention to these details, well, lesson learned. I'd advise to close this question unless it's somewhat useful for newcomers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, It’s just an invalid byte sequence in your request URL, try this one:

add into your gemfile `gem 'rack-utf8_sanitizer'` or `gem 'handle_invalid_percent_encoding_requests'` or `gem 'utf8-cleaner'` after that run `bundle install`.

Comment: somehow none of them worked, still get the same error. this is really weird.

Comment: Add the following line to your config/application.rb:

`config.middleware.use 'Utf8Sanitizer'`

Comment: I get `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'config' for main:Object` even after intalling the gem

Comment: Add the utf8_sanitizer.rb to your Rails 3.2 project in app/middleware go through this link  https://gist.github.com/joost/ca4eda8f31655cf6095a

Comment: I've returned to previous commits and now I get the error on those too, and apparently rails should always deal with this automatically unless I'm using a version prior to 2.0, right now I'm using 5.0, any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

`mount_uploaders` expects an array, and so your seed.rb file should be set up to accept an array.

It should look like this: `Model.create(images: [image1.jpg])`

Not like this: `Model.create(images: image1.jpg)`